# How to disable screen update in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have a loop that is adding a line to a plot on each iteration. Right now this is horribly slow as it seems to redraw the the whole graph each time. Is it possible to disable screen updates for a graph while it is being set up then re-enable them afterwards.

Here's the code:

```
    for rr,dd in zip(angles,dists):
        if dd == inf:
            pass
        else:
            lineend = (array([cos(rr), sin(rr)]) * dd)+origin;
            plot([origin[0], lineend[0]], [origin[1], lineend[1]],'-b');
```

I know I should just combine this all into one call to `plot` and I'll probably do it for this example. But there are other bits where that would be more of a problem so a general solution would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have the [interactive mode](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/shell.html) `on`, so you should just set it to `off` using the command

```
ioff()
```

Note that when interactive mode is off, you'll need to use the command `show()` to display the plots.

Comment: Wow, that's an incredible difference! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked for you.  I think that cases like this are exactly why a non-interactive mode exists.